# Get Video Feed of a Window on Desktop

Tags: windows, video

For an art installation, we'd like to capture the contents of a browser window, and forward these as a video stream. The browser window will display flash animations.

Is there a program that can capture the contents of a window, and provide it as a video stream?
This is on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [VideoLan - VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

How to: [How to Record Your Desktop to a File or Stream It Over the Internet with VLC](http://www.howtogeek.com/120202/how-to-record-your-desktop-to-a-file-or-stream-it-over-the-internet-with-vlc/)